# iOS8 How dynamically fixed UITableViewHeaderFooterView height size?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader, uitableviewautomaticdimension

**I use the method as follows**

I have just tried below lines of code, dynamically set the UITableViewHeaderFooterView height size.

`self.tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 100
self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

**I have the following problems**

In iOS9, iOS10 can run normally, and can display properly. But can not be displayed correctly in iOS8, and the following error is displayed:

[image]

**My analysis is as follows:**

From the error prompt, I can see that the problem is NSLayoutConstraint: 0x7f8498d7b890 _UITableViewHeaderFooterContentView: 0x7f8498cb9200.height == 0

But I have never made any Constraints to UITableViewHeaderFooterContentView

How should I fit iOS8?

Comment: Call the `updateConstraintsIfNeeded` method when you return your cell inside the `table view cell for row at` method.

`cell.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()

return cell`
This step is NOT needed for iOS 9+

Comment: This method does not work

Comment: In order to make UITableViewAutomaticDimension work you have to set all left, right, bottom, and top constraints relative to cell container view. Check did u added all four constraints...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the UIView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
    {
        [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

        [ViewHeader setNeedsLayout];
        [ViewHeader layoutIfNeeded];
        CGFloat height = [ViewHeader systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;

        CGRect headerFrame = ViewHeader.frame;
        headerFrame.size.height = height;
        ViewHeader.frame = headerFrame;
        [tbl setTableHeaderView:ViewHeader];
    }
```